When to assume someone’s a liar
If someone tells you to make up something, for example, (showing that they have no problem lying) and then afterwards they tell you something, do you have to assume it’s a lie?
Example case: you’re reporting sales numbers for your company and your boss tells you to make up something. When you prompt him that that’s not something we should do, he simply responds back with the number of sales you should write. So, do we need to assume that that number he gave is probably false and he just wanted to get you off his back, and thus you wouldn’t be allowed to report it, or can we דן לכף זכות and assume he realized the problem with making up numbers so he indeed told you the real sales numbers?
Another example for clarity: your boss wants you to advertise some deals your company has made and tells you to make up the numbers. You say “do you have any real deals we can use to advertise” and then they respond with whatever numbers and case they write. Do we assume he’s telling the truth or that he just made it up himself to alleviate the other persons worries
Edit: The halachic angle is let’s say in the last case, if we assume the boss is lying and made up the numbers then you would have to refuse to advertise that because it would be geneivat daat and מסייע עוברי עברה, but if we assume he’s telling the truth then all is well

Where's the halachic angle?

Writing a report like the OP describes, may not be the official statement. It is corporate practice that reports are made in the name of a group, not a single analyst. The "boss" may have numbers that s/he can substitute into the report when sending it up the chain.

You can't assume guilt, unless you have proof. If you strongly suspect guilt, you are free to refuse to be an accessory, even if it costs you your job.  But you don't have to.

But what about geneivat daat, or מסייע לעוברי עברה

@shmosel i edited
